# Combining for-loops in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am making a GoBoard and want to check if the Black player has won the game. I made four for loops to check, whether there are 5 stones in a row horizontally, vertically or diagonally. I would like to combine them however, to save some lines of code. How to do it? Is it possible to simply check for the White player as well using the same for loops or should I make a new bool for the White player?

```
class goBoard {
private:
  boardSquare* entrance; // A pointer containing the address of the boardSquare-object at the top left of the grid.
  void zip (boardSquare*, boardSquare*);
  boardSquare* makeRow (); //(int amount)?
  int m, n;

public:
  //goBoard ();
  goBoard (int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns);
  ~goBoard ();
  void build ();
  void computer (char colour);
  bool squareEmpty (int x, int y);
  void human (char colour);
  void print ();
  bool done ();
  bool won ();
  void makeMove (int x, int y, char colour);

};//class goBoardbool

goBoard::wonBlack () {
   boardSquare* currentSquare = entrance; //assuming that the player starts at the entrance
   bool nextSquare = true;
   if ((*currentSquare).colour == 'B') {
      for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
         if (nextSquare == true) {
            currentSquare = (*currentSquare).neighbours[2]; //.neighbours[2] is a pointer to the square to the right of the current square
            if ((*currentSquare).colour != 'B')
               nextSquare = false;
            }
      }
      for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
         if (nextSquare == true) {
            currentSquare = (*currentSquare).neighbours[4];
            if ((*currentSquare).colour != 'B')
               nextSquare = false;
            }
      }
      for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
         if (nextSquare == true) {
            currentSquare = (*(*currentSquare).neighbours[2]).neighbours[4];
            if ((*currentSquare).colour != 'B')
               nextSquare = false;
            }
      }
      for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
         if (nextSquare == true) {
            currentSquare = (*(*currentSquare).neighbours[6]).neighbours[4];
            if ((*currentSquare).colour != 'B')
               nextSquare = false;
            }
      }
      if (nextSquare == true)
         return true;
   }
   return false;
}//goBoard::won
```

Comment: Where is the index `i` being used?

Comment: Nowhere, it is the standard for loop letter that I use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce the linecount, I would go for something on this line:

```
enum class Direction {vertical, horizontal, downRight, upRight};
enum class Sign {negative, zero, positive}
enum class Semen {white, black};

template <typename Elem>
unsigned int howManyInARow(Direction direction, Sign sign, Elem elem, Semen semen){
    unsigned int ret = 0;
    if(elem == semen){
        ret = 1;
    }
    if(negative != sign)
        ret += howManInARow(direction, positive, elem.getNeighbour(direction, positive), semen);
    if(positive != sign)
        ret += howManInARow(direction, negative, elem.getNeighbour(direction, negative), semen);

    return ret;
}
```

Could'nt test it because I don't have the elements. Give it a try and I can elaborate on it if you like it

Comment: I am sorry, I am mostly a novice so I don't understand these types of variables... Would you mind if I were to send you my entire .cc file?